# How to get new 'earworm song' for six year old boy?

Tags: primary-schooler, music

My six year old boy has heard Sir Mix A Lot's song *Baby Got Back*. (From a movie I think).

The chorus has the right mixture of irreverent delight that would appeal to a six-year old.

The challenge is that we hear it at breakfast and dinner - every day for the last month. *I like big XXXXs*.

So it's time for a new song. But how? What would logically replace that song in his mind, and be appropriate?

My question is: **How to get new 'earworm song' for six year old boy?**

Comment: Play him some better music. Potentially *Queen - Fat-bottomed girls*? ;)

Comment: Try more age appropriate music, like Kids Bop CDs or something?

Comment: Or not care that it's vulgar. We chose to not gloss over words and content and teach about the truth of the society around them from the beginning. So far it seems to be working fine. In my experience, "favorite song" seems to cycle monthly. You should be out of sir mix a lot's clutches soon, and possibly into something far worse

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether he's singing it or playing it. In either case, he's much more likely to pick up a new ear worm if you play him lots of different music, so expanding music exposure, or pointing out existing music exposure is an absolute must.

If he's playing it, it's easier. You could go all out "unpleasant parent" and simply delete/block that track, but that's likely to cause tantrums and revenge singing. We implemented a "no repeats on this journey" policy for music in our car. It simply widens the range of music the kids listen to and they generally find a new favourite within a couple of months (or shorter, sometimes it's shorter...). You could have a similar policy of "no repeats between breakfast and lunch" at home.

If he's singing it, then I'd recommend not making a big deal out of it. Just express your dislike of it and encourage singing a different song of (partly) your choosing.

Sometimes, if my children were singing a song I didn't like, I'd respond by singing "Let it Go" from Frozen. It happened that everybody was singing that all the time in their lives and they were a bit sick of it (sound familiar?). They learned how annoying someone else's ear worm can be, and they were also lightly conditioned not to sing the song I didn't like.

Sadly, I now buy radio edits of songs, too. The children all know what the ***beep*** means and giggle about it, so I've developed a specific love of lyricless movie soundtracks (John Williams is particularly good).